# Any example how 2 comboxbox select work and display corresponding iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to do 2 combo box on web page

Let said Country option person choose "China" the second combobox will list all the provinces, after which if the user choose "JiangSu" for example will open a dedicate iframe underneath the 2nd combobox

Any idea how to do it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /*
    Triple Combo Script Credit
    By Philip M: http://www.codingforums.com/member.php?u=186
    Visit http://javascriptkit.com for this and over 400+ other scripts
    */

    var categories = [];
    categories["startList"] = ["China","US"]
    categories["China"] = ["ANHUI","JIANGSU"];
    categories["US"] = ["Alabama","New york"];

    var nLists = 2; // number of select lists in the set

    function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
        var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
        for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
            document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
            document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        var nCat = categories[currCat];
        for (each in nCat) {
            var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
            var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
            nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
            nOption.appendChild(nData); 
            currList.appendChild(nOption); 

        }

    }

    function getValue(L2, L1) {

        <!-- alert("Your selection was:- \n" + L1 + "\n" + L2);-->
        document.getElementById("lname").value= L1 + "\n" + L2;
    }


    function init() {
        fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
    }

    navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);           

</script>
```

html

```
<span class="favorBOfont">Country Selection</span><p>&nbsp;</p>

<form name="tripleplay" action="">
    Category: 
    <select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
        <option selected>Make a selection</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        Content:
    <select name='List2' onchange="getValue(this.value, this.form['List1'].value)">
        <option selected>Make a selection</option>
    </select>
        <!-- onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])" -->


    </p>

</form>
&nbsp;<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="88" id="lname" name="lname" size="30" height="30" readonly></textarea>
</p>
<div></div>
```

I would need an iframe statement instead of textarea property

Comment: I need an example how to accomplish this as I only got one combo box, seeking an example how does 2nd combo box will work follow by an iframe, do you have an example?

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: I uses above JS but I could not figure out how to make an iframe once the last 2nd combox value is selected, i have deleted some country name, and province to make it simple and easy to read

Comment: Replace `<textarea rows="8" cols="88" id="lname" name="lname" size="30" height="30"  readonly></textarea>` with `<iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>` then you can easily reference it and do what you want.

Comment: The question is how I assign different iframe page? This is like if I choose JiangSu for example will triggered iframe1 with corresponding html, choose Anhui will triggered another iframe with designated iframe page

Comment: So you just change the `src` property of the `iframe` to the `url` for the specific `option` that is chosen in the `select`.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I'm noob in Html

Comment: [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). `myFrame.src="http://www.google.com"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example.

```js
var nList1 = document.querySelector('select[name="List1"]'),
    nList2 = document.querySelector('select[name="List2"]'),
    myFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame'),
    categories = ["China", "US"],
    contents = {
        China: ["ANHUI", "JIANGSU"],
        US: ["Alabama", "New york"]
    }

categories.forEach(function (category) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    
    option.value = option.textContent = category;
    nList1.appendChild(option);
});

nList1.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target,
        value = target.value,
        options = nList2.options,
        content = contents[value];

    myFrame.src = '';
    nList2.selectedIndex = 0;
    while (options.length > 1) {
        nList2.removeChild(options[1]);
    }

    if (content) {
        content.forEach(function (element) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            
            option.value = option.textContent = element;
            nList2.appendChild(option);
        });
    }
}, false);

nList2.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.selectedIndex) {
        myFrame.src = '/';
    } else {
        myFrame.src = '';
    }
}, false);
```

```css
.dropDown {
    display:block;
}
#myFrame {
    margin-top:1em;
    width:100%
}
```

```html
<span class="favorBOfont">Country Selection</span>
<label class="dropDown">Category:
    <select name="List1">
        <option>Make a selection</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label>Content:
    <select name="List2">
        <option>Make a selection</option>
    </select>
</label>
<iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi Xotic750, question here your selection only got 2 iframe selection how do we add more iframe, giving that in future my combo list for province will be much more, each province will got it own iframe property window

Comment: Change the conditional to what is appropriate to your list `if (evt.target.selectedIndex) {  myFrame.src = '/';`